# Return Doctrine entity in a JSON endpoint response

Tags: json, doctrine, symfony4

How can I return a Doctrine entity in a json response using Symfony?

I have already tried the JMS/Serializer and the [symfony/serializer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) but it builds me a string with json inside, which isn't correctly parsed on the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
return base64_encode(serialize($entity));
```

Client side

```
/** @var Category $entity */
$entity = unserialize(base64_decode($response));
```

but you can't use doctrine process, like persist or flush methods